# Как заставить браузер "отрисовать" стили именно в данный момент?

Tags: javascript, style, html, dom

Не секрет, что браузеры пытаются оптимизировать отрисовку страницы и в общем случае это правильно.

Перед выполнением скрипта пытаюсь отобразить **div** через **style.display = 'block'**, после выполнения скрипта (0.9-2.4с) убираю **div** через **style.display = 'none'**, но операции с **div** съедаются оптимизатором браузера. Пробовал и с **visibility**, и с методами **jQuery**, но пока результата нет.

Как можно заставить браузер сделать моментальную отрисовку по требованию javascript?

Comment: Они съедаются, только если это происходит в одном потоке. Для принудительного repaint просто вызовите div.offsetWidth; или window.getComputedStyle(div, null);

Comment: отчасти сработало, ширину блока выдало правильно, но блок все-равно не отрисовался

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что код выглядел как-то так:

```
function runLongOperation() {
  // style.display = 'block'
  // ...долго работающий код
  // style.display = 'none'
}
```

Тогда должно сработать что-то такое:

```
// style.display = 'block'
setTimeout(function runLongOperation() {
  // ...долго работающий код
  // style.display = 'none'
}, 0);
```

PS. `offsetWidth` и `getComputedStyle` выполняют reflow/restyle, а не repaint ([тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862081/1026) ссылки на подробности), API для принудительной перерисовки не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Используй requestAnimationFrame(nameOfYourFunction) и передай имя функции как аргумент.
Это функция говорит браузеру, что скрипт окончен и он может приступать к отрисовке DOM или ответам на запросы пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
if (true) { // здесь любое условие
   var styles      = document.createElement ("link");
       styles.rel  = "stylesheet";
       styles.href = "theme.css"
    document.body.appendChild (styles);
```